# Number of possibilities

Tags: combinations

If I have a limitless quantity of shirts that come in x colors. I need to pack y shirts per pack being shipped. No more than 2 of one color can be shipped per pack. How do I determine the number of unique combinations if order doesn't matter?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  when you ask a question you are expected to show your efforts so that others can help you

Comment: I have no idea where to start. I don't even know where to start with a Google search to read how to learn.